# Western Union has hijacked my home page

Tags: internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

cannot reset homepage in IE9. Western Union has hijacked my home page...internet options.general
does not work.., western union comes back everytime. Help!

Answer (score 3):

Chances are, that's not actually Western Union. I recommend installing [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), updating it, and running a full scan on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I would tr to use ASC (advanced System care by iOBIT) first, if it doesnt fix it. try my pc> tools>folder options> enable show hidden files. then go to C:\users or (Documents and settings) then select user> app data> local low and look for a .exe with a nonsense name (Delete it) if it does not allow you reboot and press F8 unitl you get to the bootloader and pick safe mode. delete it